# How do I replace a date in a Rest request to make it todays date for cucumber automation testing?

Tags: java, rest, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am fairly new to programming in java- I am writing a cucumber test that takes a Rest request with multiple dates in the request and then validates the response for certain strings of characters. Here is an example request:

```
    {
  "id": "1245",
  "paymentAmount" :  404,
  "paymentPending": [
    {
      "paymentNumber": 1,
      "paymentAmount": 100,
      "paymentDate": "20191223"
    },
    {
      "paymentNumber": 2,
      "paymentAmount": 100,
      "paymentDate": "20200106"
    },
    {
      "paymentNumber": 3,
      "paymentAmount": 204,
      "paymentDate": "20200130"
    }

  ]
}
```

I want to modify the rest request without manipulating the json file. I need to change the payment dates to be todays date (in above date format) and the following dates to be todays date plus 15 days and 30 days, but this needs to be done during the actual step definition implementation. How would I do something like this? Here is a snippet of what I currently have after I get the request (for asserting the values in the request):

```
assertThat(getRequest.id()!=null);
    assertThat(getRequest.paymentAmount()!=null);
    for(paymentPendingp : getRequest.paymentPending()) {
        assertThat(p.getPaymentDate()!=null);
        assertThat(p.getPaymentAmount()!=null);
        assertThat(p.getPaymentNumber()!=null);
    }
```

I know I need to set the fields dates but I am not sure what the best way is to do it since I have the for loop within the dates that I need to modify and then assert that it is not null.

Here is the current logic I have for updating the paymentDates in the JSON request- it is currently not setting the value correctly.

```
for(Payment p : getRequest.getPayment()) {
            switch(p.getPaymentNumber()){
                case 1 :
                    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd");
                    String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
                    p.paymentDate = strDate;
                    log.info("dates are: " + strDate);
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    Date currentDate2 = new Date();
                    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c2.setTime(currentDate2);
                    c2.add(Calendar.DATE, 15);
                    Date currentDatePlusTwenty = c2.getTime();
                    DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd");
                    String strDate2 = dateFormat2.format(currentDatePlusTwenty);
                    p.paymentDate = strDate2;
                    log.info("dates are: " + strDate2);
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    Date currentDate = new Date();
                    Calendar c3 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c3.setTime(currentDate);
                    c3.add(Calendar.DATE, 29);
                    Date currentDatePlusForty = c3.getTime();
                    DateFormat dateFormat3 = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd");
                    String strDate3 = dateFormat3.format(currentDatePlusForty);
                    p.paymentDate = strDate3; 
                    log.info("dates are: " + strDate3);
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    Date currentDate4 = new Date();
                    Calendar c4 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c4.setTime(currentDate4);
                    c4.add(Calendar.DATE, 40);
                    Date currentDatePlusSixty = c4.getTime();
                    DateFormat dateFormat4 = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd");
                    String strDate4 = dateFormat4.format(currentDatePlusSixty);
                    p.paymentDate = strDate4; // also tried p.setPaymentDate(strDate4);
                    log.info("dates are: " + strDate4);
                    break;
                    default:
                        break;
            }
            assertThat(p.getPaymentDate()!=null);
            assertThat(p.getMaxAllowedDaysToSchedule()!=null);
            assertThat(p.getPaymentAmount()!=null);
            assertThat(p.getPaymentNumber()!=null);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sending the payload (json mentioned above) from your Gherik step in `.feature` file?

Comment: Hey, yes. Everything runs as expected (i'm passing the json file name in the feature file)- I just cant seem to update the JSON request from the @given statement. The request has to have todays date, then the date plus 15 days and then todays date plus 30 days. Currently I am manually changing the dates to get the tests to pass, but I need to make it so that the JSON request regardless of what the json file has for the dates automatically updates the JSON payment dates to todays date, etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: I also have another scenario that requires me to pass todays date for all the payment dates and then validate an error message and code (which is not shown in my example)

Comment: For you first comment, you have to write another step something like `And User updated xxxx.json with latest dates`. And implement the logic in the step def to update the json file with the current date and so on, save. Then you should be good to go and upload the file. I would recommend storing the dates that you are updating in json into global variables so that you can use the same to validate the response.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm going to edit my post to show you the logic I am trying to use to update the paymentDate field- I'm struggling with the implementation of the new date values.